# SQL Server Stored Procedure parameters affect speed of query - Why?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am running a stored procedure on SQL Server 2005 and calling it from a VB.net application.

This stored procedure was taking over 3 minutes to run and I started working on way to speed it up. Quite by accident I stumbled on a solution that reduced the run time from 3 minutes to 3 seconds (no joke, I'm dead serious).

But I don't understand why.

The only 2 parameters that I pass are a start date and an end date (used in the `WHERE` clause) as so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE get_OrderLinessByRegion
     @DateFrom DATETIME,
     @DateTo DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
 blah, blah, blah
```

Though some testing I found that when I hard coded the dates in the stored procedure the run times were cut from 3 minutes to 3 seconds.

I ended up with this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE get_OrderLinessByRegion
  @DateFrom DATETIME,
  @DateTo DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

       DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
       DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME

       SET @StartDate = @DateFrom
       SET @EndDate = @DateTo
       blah, blah, blah
```

Can anyone tell me why the second version runs so much faster ?

Thanks so much !!

Comment: This is a bad case of parameter sniffing. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: Hmm, I've never heard of parameter sniffing before, so I googled and found this article: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/.  Why would parameter sniffing occur when the parameters are defined as DATETIME ?  It seems that the execution plan would always have to be the same for that data type ?

Comment: Yeah that is another good article on the topic.

Comment: It isn't about the datatypes, read the article again. It is about compiled execution plan based on certain VALUES

Comment: OK, first "Duh..." is that I didn't notice that you provided a link.  The second "Duh..." is that I understand the values concept better now. Now, how do I award the answer to you ?

Comment: Are you using the params to call another stored procedure in the "blah, blah, blah" Block?

Comment: No, params are used in the WHERE clause (i.e. WHERE Date BETWEEN Param1 AND Param2).  There is no other sproc involved.

Comment: I put pretty much the same comment as an answer so you can "close" your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a case of bad parameter sniffing. You can read this article for a detailed explanation. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/